# multiple IP addresses bound - which one is used for outgoing packets?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, shorewall

Using IP aliasing a linux box has bound multiple ip addresses from the same subnet on the same NIC. So ifconfig shows up device eth0 with , eth0:1 with  and eth0:2 with .

How does Linux determine the IP source address used for outgoing ip traffic? Is there a way to define what source IP address certain outgoing traffic should use?

Comment: Just specify a netmask of `255.255.255.255` for the IPs you don't want to be used as source addresses. That will make them seem "further" from the default gateway (and other machines on that subnet) and so they won't be preferred. [See here](http://serverfault.com/a/422230/91987)

Comment: This helps at least partially. Can alternativly iptables be used for specifiying the source IP on outgoing stuff here?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the best way to do it. Better is something like `ip route replace default via GATEWAY.IP.GOES.HERE src SOURCE.IP.GOES.HERE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why he posted his answer as a comment, but David Schwartz is correct, you should set a netmask of 255.255.255.255 on the 'secondary' addresses, and you should not set gateway addresses on them. You put the correct netmask on the main address, and give it the correct gateway address.